# How to combine "Delete from" and "Delete a from query"

Tags: mysql, database, join, combinations, sql-delete

I've got 2 queries - DELETE FROM and DELETE A FROM and I'm trying to combine them into one query, I tried several ways but I still get syntax error:

1. ```
   DELETE A FROM wp_posts AS a INNER JOIN ( SELECT post_content, MIN( id
   ) AS min_id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status =
   'publish' GROUP BY post_content HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1 ) AS b ON
   b.post_content = a.post_content AND b.min_id <> a.id AND a.post_type =
   'post' AND a.post_status = 'publish'
   ```
2. ```
   DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE `post_title` like '%.png%'
   ```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE `post_title` like '%.png%'' at line 5

Comment: Does anyone have solution for this issue? Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you need to combine them into one statement at all? They're two separate delete operations.

Comment: I need to run them in one cron job script, my hosting plan has limited capacity and I don't want to run them separately by a webcron.

Comment: Then have your single script execute two database queries.